# How to use server side speaker notes of reveal.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm, reveal.js

I want to use the server side speaker notes of reveal.js so that I can use other devices to switch slides while my presentation is running on my laptop. I followed [the instructions on reveal.js github page](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#installation) and now have a full installation.

I am able to use the speaker notes on my laptop without a problem. So I tried the server side speaker notes [following these instructions](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#server-side-speaker-notes). Thus when I run the server and go to localhost:1947 using a browser a popup opens which looks like the normal speaker notes page. I now have three problems:

1) My notes do not show up in the popup page. Even though they did in the normal speaker notes page.

2) If i sweep through slides in the popup page they don't change in the main page

3) The "Upcoming" section in the popup page doesn't update. But it did in the normal speaker notes.

I'm using an ubuntu 13.10 64bit system. I have node.js v0.10.26, express 2.5.8 and grunt  v0.4.4 installed. I also installed socket.io using:

```
sudo npm install socket.io
```

Could this be some compatibility issue or is it me whose doing something wrong? I've never worked with node.js or socket.io so I'm not sure where to look.

EDIT:

I add a minimal example here. Though in order to use it you need to put it in index.html in reveal.js directory and install plugins using:

```
npm install
```

then in order to run it enter this command:

```
node plugin/notes-server/
```

you also need to have node.js and grunt installed. after running you can open the slides from localhost:1947. When you open this page a pop-up will appear which is the notes page and you should be able to change slides in the main page from there. Unfortunately I can't. 
index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>minimal sample</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reveal.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme/default.css" id="theme">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="reveal">
        <div class="slides">
            <section>
                <h1>Reveal.js</h1>
                <h3>HTML Presentations Made Easy</h3>
                <p>
                    <small>Created by <a href="http://hakim.se">Hakim El Hattab</a> / <a href="http://twitter.com/hakimel">@hakimel</a></small>
                </p>
            </section>

            <section>
                <h2>Heads Up</h2>
                <p>
                    reveal.js is a framework for easily creating beautiful presentations using HTML. You'll need a browser with
                    support for CSS 3D transforms to see it in its full glory.
                </p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="lib/js/head.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/reveal.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        Reveal.initialize({
            dependencies: [
                { src: 'socket.io/socket.io.js', async: true },
                { src: 'plugin/notes-server/client.js', async: true }
            ]
        });

    </script>

</body>
```

[image: slides]

[image: server notes (popup)]

Comment: Could you share some code? With given information, it's a bit hard to figure out what the problem could be.

Comment: I added a simple example, some explanation on how to use it and photos of output. Is there anything I need to check if I have installed? I also found this plugin https://github.com/ysmood/notell which works fine but lacks flexibility

Comment: I think you are not using correct configuration. See the configurations mentioned below [this](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#multiplexing). You have to use `multiplex .. {secret.., id.., url..}`

Comment: as it says there multiplexing is for sharing my slides with the audience. Then when I switch slides on my laptop, it's switched on their devices as well. I want the slides on my laptop change when I change it on my tablet. Also using server notes I can view the upcoming slide and my notes, but in multiplexing that's not possible

Answer (score 3):

I think Reveal.js has a problem. Pending resolution, you can close the popup window and press the '**s**' key. This will work correctly for me.